# How to debug conscrypt connections

Tags: java, ssl, networking

Usually we debug **ssl** handshake steps using **`javax.net.debug=all`** runtime variable. But this doesn't works for conscrypt connection. Is there anything equivalent available for cons-crypt connections in order to debug cons-crypt connection steps?